# Put in where sql only the date from datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database like this :

```
id              date                        origine
1              2015-12-04 16:54:38             1
```

Now I want to get only data witch have the date = `2015-12-04`. So I tried like this :

```
select * from table where id = 1 and date = "2014-12-04"
```

But I have no data. Can you help me please ?

Comment: replace 'table' with the actual table name and write SELECT * FROM table WHERE date LIKE "2014-12-04%"

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the `date` function:

```
where id = 1 and date(date) = '2015-12-04'
```

However, for performance reasons, it is often better to use inequalities.  This allows MySQL to use an index on `id, date` for the query:

```
where id = 1 and
      (date >= '2015-12-04' and date < date_add('2014-12-04', interval 1 day))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Date Function of mysql which returns date from DateTime or truncate the Time part

```
select * from table where id = 1 and Date(date) = "2014-12-04"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several date related function out there you can use, take the following:

```
select * 
from table 
where id = 1 
and date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-12-04';
```

`date_format` will format your date column to a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

In `MSSQL` you can simply say

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   ID = 1
    AND Date > '2015-12-04'
```

I'm not familiar with `mysql`, but I assume something similar would work here. This date gets formatted as `2015-12-04 00:00:00` so in effect it matches everything with a date of `2015-12-04` and a time greater than `00:00:00`.

If you happen to have rows with time of `00:00:00`, just use `>=` instead.